# Get headers from a request using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http

I'd like to get the headers form a request (ex: status code, content-lenght, content-type...). My code :

```
options = {
            method:'HEAD'
            host:"123.30.xxx.xxx"
            port:80
        }
http.request(options,(res)->
    res.send JSON.stringify(res.headers)
)
```

but this is not working

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.end()` on your `http.request()` object in order to make your request - see the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

> With http.request() one must always call req.end() to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

For example:

```
var options = {
    method:"HEAD",
    host:"google.com",
    port:80
};
var req = http.request(options,function(res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
});

req.end();
```

Another issue in your code is that `res` doesn't have a `.send()` method - if you're referring to another `res` variable (for example, containing the code that you have posted) then your variables will be conflicting. If not, you should double check what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid and it appears that you are not instantiating options as a variable prior to it's use. ev0lutions code resolves these issues as well as ending the request.

For info on how to create valid JSON check out this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: It looks like he's using Coffeescript - his code will compile to correct Javascript.